How to log Exception, telebot
I want to do error 409 processing.
This error occurs when multiple bots are running simultaneously with the same API
How many times I try, nothing works, here is the code:
(This is just a small part of the code)
import telebot 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Bot_API, parse_mode=None) 


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: re.match(r'^/start$', message.text, re.IGNORECASE)) 
def command_start(message): 
    locale = message.from_user.language_code 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, WELCOME_MESSAGE_RUSSIAN, reply_markup=keyboard) 
    contact_button = types.KeyboardButton(CONFIRM_PHONE_ENGLISH, request_contact=True) 
    keyboard.add(contact_button) 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, WELCOME_MESSAGE_ENGLISH, reply_markup=keyboard) 

while True: 
    try: 
        bot.polling(non_stop=True) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e) 
        if "Conflict" in str(e) or "409" in str(e): 
            print("Конфликт API, это происходит, когда вы пытаетесь запустить несколько экземпляров")

Don’t know how to fix that
There may be spelling errors in the sample, but I try to convey the essence, everything is fine with the code, I just don't understand why Exception doesn't work

What is it that does not work? Does it print the wrong things? Does it not catch the exception? Does it crash somewhere else? Do you get syntax error?
